# How to do specific grouping by time interval?

Tags: excel, logic, excel-2007, grouping, pivot-table

In my Excel file I have the following:

```
Row Labels.............|......Sum of Count  
***ALICERICKY....................2751***  
9/28/2012 11:42...............833  
9/28/2012 11:43...............84  
9/28/2012 12:07...............917  
9/28/2012 19:34...............138  
9/28/2012 19:35...............779  
**ALICANTIAYAA005...........78**  
9/28/2012 16:37...............78  
**BELLAVBA005..................2429**  
9/7/2012 11:34...............230  
9/7/2012 11:35...............984  
9/7/2012 11:38...............56  
9/7/2012 11:39...............1159
```

If I do a left click any timestamp and I do a left click and do a group by min, Excel will group it as per min, then sum up the values as a 5 min group.

What can I do to indicate I want to group by 5 min instead of 1? For e.g:

```
Row Labels.............|......Sum of Count  
***ALICERICKY....................2751***  
9/28/2012 11:42...............  
.........................................917   
9/28/2012 11:43...............  
9/28/2012 12:07...............917  
9/28/2012 19:34...............  
..........................................917  
9/28/2012 19:35...............
```

So for `AliceRicky`, it is summed up into 3 groups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you may need a helper column in your source data. Say equals Time value in first data row and then:

```
=IF(AND(INT((B2-40908)*288)=INT((B3-40908)*288),A2=A3),D2,B3)
```

in subsequent rows (assuming Row Labels in `ColumnA`, Time in `ColumnB`, Count in `ColumnC` and Helper column is `D`, in source).

Then pivot with the Helper column as a Row Label.

This (starting on 1/1/12 ie 1/1/1900+40908 days) bands time into 5 minute intervals (00:00:00 - 00:04:59 etc, hence 09/07/2012 11:34 is in a different band to 09/07/2012 11:35) and names these as the first time in that band, doing so separately for each Row Label. 288 is the number of 5 minutes in one day.

Comment: Hi thanks for replying, but i really cant get what u are trying to teach me.